# Data with a lot of zeroes

Tags: interpretation, dataset

Please forgive a simple-minded question. I'm looking at a dataset now of a few thousand values, and trying to analyze it statistically. Most of the values, about 90%, are zeroes, and then the rest are positive integers from 1 to about 50, with most of them under 10 (it is number of parasites found on an animal). I'm just wondering whether someone can tell me some common techniques to use in a situation like this. I thought this might be "sparse data", but when I googled that I found mostly stuff about machine learning, and it didn't seem to be what I was looking for.

Thanks for any help,
Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword you are after is [zero-inflated models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-inflated_model). You can find many questions concerning them under the [zero-inflation](/questions/tagged/zero-inflation) tag. If your data is counts, a possible candidate would be zero-inflated Poisson model.

Comment: That's the thing, thank you!